# Recommended modelling software for 200 μs pulse width pulse transformer application

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, pulse, high-current

I am looking to model a HV pulse generator that involves discharging a 6 μF capacitor at about 300 V across the primary coil of a transformer. This discharge happens about once every 1.5 seconds. The output pulse on the secondary coil should be around 6±2 kV peak and have a pulse width of around 200±100 μs.

It seems to me like the 200±100 μs pulse would be considered a "high frequency" application. I am wondering if you think LTSPICE could do an okay job of modelling the peak voltage and pulse width of this circuit? I do not care so much about the pulse shape, but roughly the peak and its width. If LTSPICE is not sufficient, what other software could supplement the LTSPICE models?

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Hundreds of microseconds is hardly high frequency.

Comment: The simulator doesn't much matter; I could lash up a basic equivalent model in an Excel spreadsheet in a couple dozen minutes (not to brag, just to say it's not hard when one knows what to do). The real hard part is: to what precision do you need the waveform, what about it do you really need to know, and how accurately characterized is your transformer?

Comment: I am new to stack exchange so I do not know how to reply but thanks a lot Hearth and Tim Williams for the help

Answer (score 0):

As no specifications about the pulse (what kind) are done,  this circuit should be of interest.
As example.

[image]

If new specifications are made, the circuit could be updated.